# Applying FDR in Correlation analysis

Tags: correlation, false-discovery-rate

In the case of correlation analysis, we think that correlation coefficient and graph are much more important than p-value. This is because if the number of samples is sufficient (> 30~40), the p value easily drops to less than 0.05 regardless of the correlation coefficient and graph. For example, if 100 random numbers are set as x and y axis values, the null hypothesis assumes that there is no absolute relationship between x and y (horizontal line relationship).  That is, there must be a horizontal relationship between x and y values. We know it's impossible. Random numbers are always tilted slightly to the right or to the left. So the p-value is always under 0.05.
Anyway, there is a problem here. When applying the FDR method to the general correlation, we observed a good (high-scoring) r, rho correlation coefficient loss.
I am not sure if it is fair to lose a high correlation coefficient relationship due to a less important p-value(FDR) in a correlation analysis model.
What do you think of this issue?

Comment: If you have a specific problem, please edit your question to clarify. CV is a Q&A, not a discussion forum, so *what do you think* questions are is likely to attract close votes for being too broad / primarily opinion based.

Comment: '*Random numbers are always tilted slightly to the right or to the left. So the p-value is always under 0.05.*'. This is a dubious claim. And I say this despite being sceptical of analyses that focus on p-values.

Comment: Thanks. I see. That's uncertain assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find few people who are more "anti-p value" than I am. Nevertheless, your question makes several false assumptions that reveal some confusion.

If you generate truly random noise, then you will get p < 0.05 about 5\% of the time. That is pretty much what a p value means. Random numbers are, indeed, always "tilted" one way or another, but they are only significantly tilted at the rate you set. This is pretty easy to test. Here is R code for 3 tests with N = 1000 (you could improve this code to show 100 runs, if you wanted, but I wanted to keep it simple so it is clear, even for non-R users):

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)

cor.test(x,y) #p = 0.07

x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)

cor.test(x,y) #p = 0.79

x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- rnorm(1000)

cor.test(x,y) #p = 0.80
```

As to your more general question, I'm unclear exactly what you are asking. What to do with results of a statistical analysis is a very broad question. However, if you want to show the results of a correlation, you can show r, its standard error and the 95% CI around it. A scatter plot will also be helpful.

If you want some "test" then you could set a given correlation coefficient as "high enough to be interesting" before starting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I think I am confused with it. In Motulsky's book, "Intuitive statistics", he wrote that correlation coefficient and graph is more important than p-value in correlation analysis. I think so. At this point  I am very curious if I do multi comparison adjustment with false discovery rate, that can kill some good r(rho) scored correlation comparisons. is it a violation of the correlation assumption? Or does this FDR adjustment process just ignore more important correlation result like correlation coefficient or graph?

Comment: I have the same question as user2705000 had.